# How to add a type forward to an existing Castle Windsor registration

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm currently registering a bunch of stuff at one point in my initialisation sequence

```
Container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<MyAssembly>()
    .BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .WithService.Self().Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient));
```

I'm using WithService.Self so that it doesn't automatically pick up AllInterfaces, so that the interface that I will want to add later on as a type forward has not already been added.

I'd like then (later on) to be able to add a type forward to one of the already registered components, and Intellisense on the ForwardedTypes property suggested using .Forward(typof()) e.g.

```
Container.Register(Component.For<IOtherInterface>()
    .Forward(typeof(IOtherInterface))
    .ImplementedBy<AlreadyRegisteredType>().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I've been trying to get the stuff that Krzysztof has suggested working so I've generated a test project (below). I've tried various combinations to get the ConfigureFor to forward IMyInterface to MySecondType, but just can't get it to work, when done as a second step after initial registration of my component types. I'm probably being dim, but I'm just not getting how the ConfigureFor command works, and the documentation is a little sketchy (non-existant) on the subject.

```
namespace TestProject1
{
    public class MyType : IMyInterface
    {
        public virtual string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MySecondType : IMyInterface
    {
        public virtual string MySecondProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IMyInterface
    {
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //New Container
            var container = new WindsorContainer();

            //Register Types
            container.Register(
                AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<MyType>().BasedOn<IMyInterface>().WithService.Self().Configure(
                    c => c.LifeStyle.Transient));

            //Other stuff happens here...

            //Now Register our interface as a forward
            container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<IMyInterface>()
                    .BasedOn<IMyInterface>()
                    .WithService.Base()
                    .ConfigureFor<IMyInterface>(r => r.Forward<MySecondType>()).Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient));

            var typeA = new MySecondType();
            var typeB = container.Resolve<IMyInterface>();

            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeB.GetType(), typeA.GetType());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK it was simple... Actually the error was complaining about the "key", nothing else so the solution was simple:

    Container.Register(Component.For<IOtherInterface>()
        .Forward(typeof(IOtherInterface))
        .Named("IOtherInterface")
        .ImplementedBy<AlreadyRegisteredType>().LifeStyle.Transient);

just to change the name of the Key. I would post this as an answer, but i can't for another 7 hours... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described in the comment is registering another component for the `AlreadyRegisteredType`.

If you want to add a forward to the same component use

```
ConfigureFor<AlreadyRegisteredType>(c => c.Forward<IOtherInterface>())
```

full example:

```
Container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                    .BasedOn<IEmptyService>()
                    .WithService.Base()
                    .ConfigureFor<EmptyServiceComposite>(r => r.Forward<EmptyServiceComposite>()));
```

Comment: You are quite right, I haadn't noticed the distinction, but I see that it could be important under some circumstances. Your answer looks like it is heading in the right direction, however ConfigureFor is only available within the AllTypes root, and I just tried to select the type I require using BasedOn and then ConfigureFor with no success. Is there any way of directly configuring an already registered component that I'm missing? (or am I just being dim? ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. See the full example I added to my response which forwards from `BasedOn` registration

Comment: Sorry, was away for a couple of days. I'll have a look at what you suggest tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that I still can't get it working. I've edited the question with a test project that I'm using to try and understand how this stuff goes together. I've tried various combinations, but so far, I haven't got it going. The initial components register fine, but the additional forward is never registered.

Comment: Despite all efforts I have not been able to get type forwarding working unless it is set up when the component is initially registered. Any attempt to add it later on just seems to fail. Has anyone else managed this?

Comment: re: your edit - that's to be expected. Why do you want to add a forward afterwards again? Registration should be atomic

Comment: I am building a dynamic system where it is possible for the object required to be returned for a certain base type, may change during it's lifetime. e.g. a new version. I am now abstracting that a layer further down with an "object factory" approach, however I maintain that it would be nice to be able to add and remove type-forwards within the IoC container at runtime as that way, all "resolutions" are in the one place. I'll mark as answered, since we've established that it can't be done, and thanks for your help!

Comment: yeah, it certainly goes against the intended usage :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you registered some type

```
Container.Register(Component.For<SomeType>());
```

you can forward some interface to it in this way:

```
Container.Register(Component.For<ISomeInterface>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod<ISomeInterface>(kernel => kernel.Resolve<SomeType>()));
```